# How to do USC Class Title seach on USPTO

Tags: uspto, us-class

Is it possible to do search class numbers based on the title, text or description related to the class. On EPO and WIPO one can search for classes based on text search.

I could not find any such feature on USPTO. Number search is only available with USPTO.

Answer (score 3):

Recently the US and EPO adopted a new merged classification system CPC. I would use the [EPO's CPC page](http://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/helpful-resources/first-time-here/classification/cpc.html) to keyword search for classes and then use those classes in a US search by CPC classification.

Comment: The ["Means for lengthening or shortening an element such as a table leg"](https://worldwide.espacenet.com/publicationDetails/biblio?FT=D&date=19450606&DB=&locale=en_EP&CC=GB&NR=569723A&KC=A&ND=5#) is a very funny patent, but it is not the [official EPO CPC landing page](http://www.epo.org/searching-for-patents/helpful-resources/first-time-here/classification/cpc.html).

Answer (score 1):

Look at the classification here. You can download the pdf and search in this.

http://www.uspto.gov/web/patents/classification/selectnumwithtitle.htm

Furthermore you can use the uspto advanced search and use the operater ccl/ (current classification):

http://patft.uspto.gov/netahtml/PTO/search-adv.htm